# Google structure data not working

Tags: css, html, google-search-console

I have a website and url is *altde.com*. I have written some posts in this website. Url of one post is http://altde.com/check-2g-3g-internet-data-balance-in-airtel-prepaid/

I have added class="entry-title" in main headline.

```
<h1 class="entry-title title">Check 2G 3G internet data balance in airtel prepaid</h1>
```

But i can not see it in structure data testing tool. You can test it here https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/?url=http://altde.com/check-2g-3g-internet-data-balance-in-airtel-prepaid/

Also in Google web master tools, structure data section is showing error that is entry-title missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, I must enclose all the article in a

```
<div class="hentry">
```

tag and all works!